# Move Navbar to Side if Child Route is Open

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Just learning Ember.js, playing with a toy project but am stumped in how to implement this type of functionality:

I have 4 options when I first hit the template, they are centered. When I select one, the 4 options are moved to the side and the child template is rendered to the right of the menu. If my controller has a `only-parent` boolean, then I imagine this could work. Problem is, how do I change `only-parent` when one one of the options is pressed.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="parent">
    {{#if only-parent}}
         {{#link-to classNames="center-class" 'child1'}} option1 {{/link-to}}
         {{#link-to classNames="center-class" 'child2'}} option2 {{/link-to}}
         {{#link-to classNames="center-class" 'child3'}} option3 {{/link-to}}
         {{#link-to classNames="center-class" 'child4'}} option4 {{/link-to}}
    {{else}}
         {{#link-to classNames="left-class" 'child1'}} option 1 {{/link-to}}
         {{#link-to classNames="left-class" 'child2'}} option 2 {{/link-to}}
         {{#link-to classNames="left-class" 'child3'}} option 3 {{/link-to}}
         {{#link-to classNames="left-class" 'child4'}} option 4 {{/link-to}}
         <div class="right-class">
           {{ outlet }}
         </div>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe actions is better way to accomplish it:

```
App.ParentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    hideMenu: function(hide){
        this.set('controller.only-parent', hide);
    }
  }
});

App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  activate: function () {
     this.send('hideMenu', true);
  },
  deactivate:function(){
    this.send('hideMenu', false);
  }

});
```

I this case you don't need to hardcode controller names and the solution can be used for either nested route.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure corresponding controller and every other that you want inside router.

```
App.ParentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('only-parent', true);
  }
});

App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('parent').set('only-parent', false);
  }
});
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/